# pythonのプログラム実行結果がIDLEで表示されません

Tags: python

既出でしたら申し訳ありません。

質問：IDLEの実行結果を表示する方法を教えていただけませんか。
環境：python2.7.10(Mac OS high Sierra 10.13.2)
やりたいこと：

以下のソースコードをIDLEから実行して出力結果を確認したい

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import urllib.request
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

def main(url):
    xmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    tree = ElementTree(file=xmlfile)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for node in root.getchildren():
        if node.tag == "{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05}Items":
            for subnode in node.getchildren():
                if subnode.tag == "{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05}TotalResults":
                    print(subnode.text)
                elif subnode.tag == "{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05}Item":
                    for item in subnode:
                        if item.tag == "{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05}ASIN":
                            print(item.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    amazon_api_url = "http://ecs.amazonaws.jp/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemSearch&"
    AWSAccessKeyId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    Keywords = "Python"
    url = amazon_api_url + "AWSAccessKeyId=" + AWSAccessKeyId + "&SearchIndex=Books&Keywords=" + Keywords
    main(url)
```

やったこと：
①ターミナルでIDLEと入力

②IDLEが起動するため、ファイルを開くを選択

③amazon.py(上のソースコード)を選択
（アクセスキーIDは伏せております）

④Run→Runmoduleを選択

上記を行うと、IDLEでRestartと表示された後に結果が何も表示されずに帰って
きてしまいます。

翔泳社の「１０日で覚えるPython入門教室」を参考にしていますが、期待結果と
異なっております。

なんらかの初歩的な設定ミスかと思いますが、もし同じようなはまった方がいたら
ご教示願います。

Answer (score 2):

if文で条件が成立した場合にしか表示されない(print文が実行されない）プログラムになっていますから、何が起きているのか判らないのだ思います。

if文の前に、条件判定するデータをprintするようにすると、どこで問題が発生しているかを推測できると思います。たとえば以下の例のようにmainを書き換えて実行してみてください。

```
def main(url):
xmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
tree = ElementTree(file=xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()
for node in root.getchildren():
    print node
    if node.tag == "{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05}Items":
        for subnode in node.getchildren():
            print subnode
            if subnode.tag == "{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05}TotalResults":
                print(subnode.text)
            elif subnode.tag == "{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05}Item":
                for item in subnode:
                    print item
                    if item.tag == "{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05}ASIN":
                        print(item.text)
```